# How do you build libunwind on i386 FreeBSD?

Tags: porting, freebsd, endianness, configure, stack-unwinding

libunwind is available as a package (pkg_add -r libunwind) on FreeBSD 8.1 amd64.

It is not available that way on FreeBSD 8.1 i386.

When I download from http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/ I cannot build it.

The error is 
In file included from ptrace/_UPT_elf.c:4:
../include/libunwind_i.h:65:5: error: #error Host has unknown byte-order.
*** Error code 1

This appears to be a ./configure error. Is there a way to force this information at configuration time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page: http://www.freshports.org/devel/libunwind/
libunwind is available for i386 and has been fixed on August the 12th.

If the package is not available, you can then probably build it from ports.

Comment: [root@si-fbsd8x32a /usr/ports/devel/libunwind]# make ===> libunwind-20100430 is marked as broken: does not build. *** Error code 1 Stop in /usr/ports/devel/libunwind. BUT... using 'git' and getting the latest version from their repository produced a version that built OK on 32-bit FreeBSD 8.1. THIS WORKED: git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/libunwind.git

Comment: Well you should probably update your source tree because this version seems to be obsolete, please refer once again to the link I posted. it should be libunwind-20100809_1.